# Kotlin/native support for any Kotlin library ?

Tags: kotlin, graphql, apollo, kotlin-native

Does Kotlin/native support any library written in Kotlin, for sharing common code with an iOS project ?

Specifically is there a way to use the [apollo-android](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android#kotlin) library in a shared kotlin/native project?

Comment: It is my dream library too. The implementation of Apollo to Kotlin/native would change the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no.

K/N will not support just any library written in Kotlin. I've looked at Apollo specifically, and much of that is actually Java, so you'd be pretty far off.

K/N supports "standard lib" Kotlin, which is a common subset of Kotlin, plus native extensions. Most likely, if you were going to do something like Apollo you'd want to build a multiplatform library. It would be a fair amount of work.

Comment: Do you possibly have documentation links for what is actually available from  "standard lib" and "native extensions" please?